# package requirements syntax in JSON files

Tags: node.js

In `.json` files that list package requirements sometimes packages are listed like this:
`"php": ">=5.5.0"`
and sometimes they are listed like this:
`"php": "^7.1"`

The first one suggests that the PHP package for this example must be "greater than or equal to" version 5.5.0.  But what does the second one mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/npm/node-semver#advanced-range-syntax:

> When parsing caret ranges, a missing patch value desugars to the number 0, but will allow flexibility within that value, even if the major and minor versions are both 0.

```
^1.2.x := >=1.2.0 <2.0.0
^0.0.x := >=0.0.0 <0.1.0
^0.0 := >=0.0.0 <0.1.0
```

A great tool for testing semver syntax is https://semver.npmjs.com/.